Ubuntu 24.04 (Noble Numbat) is now released and is no longer off-topic
Ubuntu 24.04 (a.k.a. Noble Numbat) is now released. As of "Thu Apr 25 15:20:52 UTC 2024", posts about it are no longer off-topic on Ask Ubuntu. As usual, posts still need to meet the other requirements to be on-topic.
Additionally, please refrain from re-opening questions about Ubuntu 24.04 that were posted prior to its release without Meta consensus. They can be re-opened, but it needs to be agreed upon via a Meta discussion first.
See also Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (Noble Numbat) released on the mailing list.

I suggest this Q&A is the official dupe target for questions about upgrading (prematurely) to 24.04 from both 23.10 and 22.04 (since answers cover both scenarios):
Cannot upgrade from Ubuntu 23.10 or 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04
